# Is it possible to rank search results lower based on the file path in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are certain files that I'd like to always appear below other files in the search results. E.g. generated files and tests. I don't want to exclude them from the search results. Usually, I'd be searching for files that aren't generated or tests. There's a setting called "Search: Sort Order", but none of them work because the files I want to de-rank are interspersed with other files.

Is there a setting or extension that could work?

Comment: Accepting implies it's the correct answer, I upvoted your answer because it's not a wrong answer, but it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible with the current LTS version of Visual Studio Code.

However, if you want the feature to be available, and many people also want it, you can make a new [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) with the tag `feature-request`. Microsoft might review it (if there are many people who want it too), and add the feature.

**Edit:** This link at Visual Studio Code might help. **[Click here for the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved).**